# How to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg on Debian 8 Jessie (No installation candidate)

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, gstreamer, apt

On a clean Debian 8 installation i had to install some gstreamer-plugins. While most of them were already installed or were easily installable via apt-get, gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg was not installable:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

threw out following warnings:

> Package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>   E: Package
>   'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

How can i install the package anyhow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no package, so you cannot install it.

Debian has switched to `libav` in favour of `ffmpeg`, and the `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` package currently cannot be be build using `libav`. hence it is not jessie.

You might have luck (or not) using one of the `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` packages on some [ubuntu PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/gstffmpeg-keep) (use them at your own risk).

Btw, `gstreamer0.10` has reached it's end-of-life a while ago. Debian/stretch (the next Debian release) will have gstreamer0.10 removed.

Update: recently (2015/06) Debian has decided to switch back from `libav`  to `ffmpeg`. However, I don't think that this will make `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` reappear.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Qt & [Qt Multimedia](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) on Debian Jessie and I realized Qt Multimedia uses the GStreamer multimedia framework as the backend for audio and video playback on Linux.

The way of getting all the required packages which are not available in Debian Jessie was using the repo for the wheezy distribution.

Adding the next repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg pluging is available via `apt-get`.

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to install the [Debian multimedia repository](http://deb-multimedia.org/):

1. Add this line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
   ```
2. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Then, you will need the key of this repo, that you can get with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
   ```
4. And now, again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. After these steps above, you can safely execute:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
   ```

Comment: adding `deb-multimedia.org` as an apt-source is known to break Debian systems and using it is actively [discouraged by the Debian project](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMultimedia/FAQ#There_is_.27Debian_Multimedia_Maintainers.27_and_.27deb-multimedia.org.27._So_what.27s_the_difference.3F)